# Embed AutoStart Does not Work

Tags: html, mysql, embed, autostart

I have a problem about HTML EMBED tag. Autostart is not working. I am very new at this thing and I stuck at this point. I am trying to do a music playlist for my users and when a user creates a playlist more than one songs it all started at the same time when page loads. I searched google and find something but they didnt work at me.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo '<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success" data="' . $row['ID'] . '"><div>' . $row['Name'] . '</div><embed class="player" autostart = "false" autoplay = "false" type = "audio/mpeg" src="'.$row['Path'].'"></embed></li>';
}
```

here is the embed code of mine.I added autostart = "false" and autoplay = "false" and type audio/mpeg but it didnt work for me?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, I am searching for something similar and ran across your post.  I think you would say autoplay=1 or autoplay=0   meaning true or false.

Comment: Please don't guess when making answers.  You're likely to get downvoted if you guess, particularly if you're wrong.